# How can I pass a column name to a is.na function via dot-dot-dot?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that takes the column name of a data frame as a `...` argument and passes it to `is.na` within a `dplyr::mutate` function call. The following toy example illustrates the basic goal:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~value,
  "a",  1,
  "a",  2,
  NA,   3,
  "b",  4
)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(avg = if_else(is.na(id), NA_real_, mean(value)))
```

The above yields the desired outcome, but not via a function.

The following function works, but does not populate the avg column with NAs as desired:

```
my_fun1 <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    mutate(avg = mean(value))
}

my_fun1(df, id)
```

The following function yields an error indicating "is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'":

```
my_fun2 <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    mutate(avg = if_else(is.na(...), NA_real_, mean(value)))
}

my_fun2(df, id)
```

Why does this error result, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: If you are passing more than one column in grouping then how does the `if_else` work out

Comment: As you are using `...`, the user can input `id1`, `id2`, etc..  Suppose, if there are more than one input, the `is.na(...)` would assume to do this on multiple columns and it will be a matrix

Comment: I see. Is there a way to use `...` so that the user can input only one column? If so, would that solve the problem?

Comment: Generally the `...` is used for multiple column input or assuming that we don't know how many groups OP have.  If you have a fixed one.  why not create a formal argument i..e `function(.data, grpcol)`

Comment: you may check the solution posted as it is more direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a fixed column, then passing unquoted argument is easy i.e. use curly-curly operator

```
myfun <- function(.data, grpcol) {
   .data %>%
          group_by({{grpcol}}) %>%
          mutate(avg = if_else(is.na({{grpcol}}), NA_real_, 
            mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
          ungroup
}
```

-testing

```
> myfun(df, id)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    value   avg
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1   1.5
2 a         2   1.5
3 <NA>      3  NA  
4 b         4   4
```

---

Or if we want to use `...` and in case if the user inputs more than one column name, select the first one always

```
myfun <- function(.data, ...) {

grps <- rlang::ensyms(...)[[1]]

.data %>%
   group_by(!! grps) %>%
   mutate(avg = if_else(is.na(!!grps), NA_real_, 
               mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
             ungroup


}
myfun(df, id)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    value   avg
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1   1.5
2 a         2   1.5
3 <NA>      3  NA  
4 b         4   4
```